# Compiling multiple schemas into different packages using JAXB 2.1

Tags: jaxb

I have a CommonTypes.xsd which I'm including in my all other XSDs using xs:include. I get

```
Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target namespace ""
```

when I try to compile it into different packages using binding files. Please tell me whether there is a way to compile them into different packages. I'm using jaxb 2.1

Comment: Please add an example binding file to your question

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, there is a way.
Assuming:

```
xsd/common/common.xsd
xsd/foo/foo.xsd
```

In the common directory place `common.xjb`:

```
<jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:package name="mypkg.common">
    </jxb:package>
</jxb:schemaBindings>
```

In the foo directory place `foo.xjb`:

```
<jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:package name="mypkg.foo">
     </jxb:package>
</jxb:schemaBindings>
```

In the `build.xml` file, create one xjc task for each:

```
<xjc destdir="${app.src}" readOnly="true" package="mypkg.common">
    <schema dir="${app.schema}/common" includes="*.xsd" />
    <binding dir="${app.schema}/common" includes="*.xjb" />
</xjc>
<xjc destdir="${app.src}" readOnly="true" package="mypkg.foo">
    <schema dir="${app.schema}/foo" includes="*.xsd" />
    <binding dir="${app.schema}/foo" includes="foo.xjb" />
</xjc>
```

You need to make sure that `common.xsd` has a `targetNameSpace` that is different from `foo.xsd`'s `targetNameSpace`.

Comment: ick, is there no way to have ONE xjb file?  We have 20 xsds so I hate having 20 xjb files.

Comment: Yes - you can have multiple <jxb:schemaBindings> in a single .xjb file.

Comment: @tdrury no, it is not possible when `<jxb:schemaBindings>` refers to same `targetnamespace`.

Answer (score 6):

As stated already by Ben there is no way to do that if they have the same namespace.
But how to do it if you do have different namespaces?

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <jxb:bindings namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/unqualifieddatatypes/1.1" schemaLocation="oagi/Common/UNCEFACT/ATG/CoreComponents/UnqualifiedDataTypes.xsd" >
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.test.oagi.udt"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/codelists" schemaLocation="oagi/Common/OAGi/Components/CodeLists.xsd" >
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:package name="com.test.oagi.cl"/>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

but be sure you do not use the command line parameter -p, since that will override your config.

Answer (score 5):

I've meet the same problem and haven't solve it yet, but I'm afraid that it can't be possible to generate XSD into differents packages :

> It is not legal to have more than one <jaxb:schemaBindings>  per namespace, so it is impossible to have two schemas in the same target namespace compiled into different Java packages

from [**Compiler Restrictions** at the end of this page](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html)

but if some one find some work around, just inform us please

Answer (score 4):

I know it is an old post, but, as there is no answer for the exact question, here is my proposal:

As mmoossen explained, **the trick is to specify different namespaces for the XSDs**.
But, adding a `namespace` attribute in the `jxb:bindings` tag doesn't work:

```
<jxb:bindings namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/unqualifieddatatypes/1.1" schemaLocation="oagi/Common/UNCEFACT/ATG/CoreComponents/UnqualifiedDataTypes.xsd" >
```

Instead of that, **you need to add a `targetNamespace` attribute to the `xs:schema` tags of your XSDs**:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    targetNamespace="some.namespace"
    version="1.0">
```

Once done, you will be able to have **1 external customization file** (.xjb) declaring **different `schemaBindings`**, each of them possibly **using a different package**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox inherit">


    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="MyFirstXSD.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.test.a" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="MySecondXSD.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.test.b" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="MyThirdXSD.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="com.test.c" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done as mentioned in jaxb maven plugin usage page in case of having  Multiple schemas with different configuration.

Separate packages can be configured for each schema.

```
<packageName>se.west</packageName>
```

complete example configuration below:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>xjc-schema1</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Use all XSDs under the west directory for sources here. -->
            <sources>
                <source>src/main/xsds/west</source>
            </sources>

            <!-- Package name of the generated sources. -->
            <packageName>se.west</packageName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>xjc-schema2</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Use all XSDs under the east directory for sources here. -->
            <sources>
                <source>src/main/xsds/east</source>
            </sources>

            <!-- Package name of the generated sources. -->
            <packageName>se.east</packageName>

            <!--
                Don't clear the output directory before generating the sources.
                Clearing the output directory removes the se.west schema from above.
            -->
            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```