# Ant task to convert WSDL to POJO with the use of XJC gives an Error package name

Tags: ant, wsdl, xjc, jdk1.7

I have an Ant task that takes a wsdl file and should auto generate POJO's (client side Java) , so I can start programming my client side JAX-WS web services.

However I'm getting an error "[ERROR] The package name .... used for this schema is not a valid package name"

This error only occurs when my *wsdl* file has more than 1 schema import in it such as

```
            <xsd:import namespace="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Response" schemaLocation="ProcessCustomerInquiryResponse.xsd"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Request" schemaLocation="ProcessCustomerInquiryRequest.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
```

Below is the entire wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:CMSLINK="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry" xmlns:REQ="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Request" xmlns:RESP="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Response" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry" name="ProcessCustomerInquiryService">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Response" schemaLocation="ProcessCustomerInquiryResponse.xsd"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Request" schemaLocation="ProcessCustomerInquiryRequest.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="ProcessCustomerInquiryRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="requestData" element="REQ:ProcessCustomerInquiryRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ProcessCustomerInquiryResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="responseData" element="RESP:ProcessCustomerInquiryResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ESB_ProcessCustomerInquiryService">
        <wsdl:operation name="ReqResp">
            <wsdl:input name="processRequest" message="CMSLINK:ProcessCustomerInquiryRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output name="processResponse" message="CMSLINK:ProcessCustomerInquiryResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ProcessCustomerInquiryServiceSoapBinding" type="CMSLINK:ESB_ProcessCustomerInquiryService">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ReqResp">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="process"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ProcessCustomerInquiryService">
        <wsdl:port name="ProcessCustomerInquiry" binding="CMSLINK:ProcessCustomerInquiryServiceSoapBinding">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://tsesbd01.tms.toyota.com:51180/v2/MF_CMSLINK_ProcessCustomerInquiryDistributed.msgflow"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

---

The XJC Ant task

```
<project name="WSDLCompile" default="wsdl2java" basedir=".">
    <target name="wsdl2java" description="Run xjc -wsdl.">
        <!-- properties -->
        <property name="sourceDir" value="temp/src" />
        <echo message="sourceDir:"/>
        <echo message="${sourceDir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="temp/classes"/>
        <property name="outputDir" value="temp/classes" />
        <echo message="outputDir:"/>
        <echo message="${outputDir}"/>
        <!-- xjc properties -->
        <property name="wsdl.url" value="src/wsdl/cmslink/ProcessCustomerInquiry.wsdl" />
        <echo message="wsdl.url:"/>
        <echo message="${wsdl.url}"/>
        <property name="wsdl.mapping.package.response" value="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Response=com.tms.cmslink.rts.service.ProcessCustomerInquiry.Response" />
        <echo message="wsdl.mapping.package.response:"/>
        <property name="wsdl.mapping.package.request" value="http://service.rts.cmslink.tms.com/ProcessCustomerInquiry/Request=com.tms.cmslink.rts.service.ProcessCustomerInquiry.Request" />
        <echo message="wsdl.mapping.package.request:"/>
        <!--C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/xjc -->
        <!--xjc execution-->
        <exec executable="xjc">
            <arg value="-wsdl" />
            <arg value="${wsdl.url}" />
            <arg value="-d" />
            <arg value="${outputDir}" />
            <arg value="-p"/>
            <arg value="${wsdl.mapping.package.request}"/>
            <arg value="-p"/>
            <arg value="${wsdl.mapping.package.response}"/>
            <arg value="-verbose"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

If I remove the extra schema import either *response.xsd* or *request.xsd*, and also only include 1 "-p" package namespace argument for the ANT task, than the ANT runs without error, however my wsdl file contains multiple schema imports.

**EDIT**

I changed the value of "-p" arguement to adhere to package conventions, although my previous approach was based on JXC bug forum.

```
<project name="WSDLCompile" default="wsdl2java" basedir=".">
    <target name="wsdl2java" description="Run xjc -wsdl.">
        <!-- properties -->
        <property name="sourceDir" value="temp/src" />
        <echo message="sourceDir:"/>
        <echo message="${sourceDir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="temp/classes"/>
        <property name="outputDir" value="temp/classes" />
        <echo message="outputDir:"/>
        <echo message="${outputDir}"/>
        <!-- xjc properties -->
        <property name="wsdl.url" value="src/wsdl/cmslink/ProcessCustomerInquiry.wsdl" />
        <echo message="wsdl.url:"/>
        <echo message="${wsdl.url}"/>
        <property name="wsdl.mapping.package.response" value="com.tms.cmslink.rts.service.ProcessCustomerInquiry.Response" />
        <echo message="wsdl.mapping.package.response:"/>
        <property name="wsdl.mapping.package.request" value="com.tms.cmslink.rts.service.ProcessCustomerInquiry.Request" />
        <echo message="wsdl.mapping.package.request:"/>
        <!--C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/xjc -->
        <!--xjc execution-->
        <exec executable="xjc">
            <arg value="-wsdl" />
            <arg value="${wsdl.url}" />
            <arg value="-d" />
            <arg value="${outputDir}" />
            <arg value="-p"/>
            <arg value="${wsdl.mapping.package.request}"/>
            <arg value="-p"/>
            <arg value="${wsdl.mapping.package.response}"/>
            <arg value="-verbose"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

I have even tried the above ant task,with

```
-p <arg value="${wsdl.mapping.package.request }"/>
<arg value="${wsdl.mapping.package.response}"/>
```

by putting both package names on 1 line separated by space, this is according to JXC doc , explaining you can have "zero or more package namespaces separated by space". I require XJC to be able to handle more than 1 schema import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-p` option specifies a *single* Java package that should be used for *all* generated classes regardless of namespace.  If you want each namespace URI to map to its own package then you can't use `-p`, you instead need to use a binding customization file

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.1">
  <bindings schemaLocation="ProcessCustomerInquiryResponse.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.example.inquiry.response"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
  <bindings schemaLocation="ProcessCustomerInquiryRequest.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <schemaBindings>
      <package name="com.example.inquiry.request"/>
    </schemaBindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

and pass it to `xjc` using the `-b` option

```
<arg value="-b"/>
<arg file="bindings.xjb"/>
```

Comment: Please specify how I can pass this binding customization to my ANT task, whats the syntax ??? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I tried it works , however I went with Apache CFX implementation, there is no need for custom bindings file in CFX, it handles multiple schema imports in wsdl automatically , Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your Ant script. There are two problems:

1. The value of the package property must be a java package. Eg: `<property name="wsdl.mapping.package" value="com.mycompany.xml.generated"/>`
2. You should only specify the one package not two.

Good luck!

Also, here's a link for a [package per schema approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3390053/1050766).

-Muel